# Каково состояние объектов стандартной библиотеки после перемещения?

Tags: c++, vector, move, unique-ptr

Скажите, пожалуйста, в каком состоянии находятся объекты стандартной библиотеки после перемещения? Можно ли продолжать их использовать?

Например, можно ли делать так:

```
std::unique_ptr<Object> object_1 = std::make_unique<Object>();
std::unique_ptr<Object> object_2 = std::move(object_1);
object_1 = std::make_unique<ConcreteObject>();
```

И так:

```
std::vector<int> v_1 {1, 2};
std::vector<int> v_2 = std::move(v_1);
v_1.push_back(1);
```

Comment: Из [ответа на вопрос "C++, std::move(), POD типы и неопределенное поведение"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1044916/208074): `В "корректное, но неопределенное состояние" попадают некоторые стандартные классы после перемещения. Например std::string: "left in valid, but unspecified state". (А некоторые нет. Например std::vector: "guaranteed to be empty()"`.).`

Comment: @Arhad-the-dev, спасибо.

Comment: См. также: [Можно ли присваивать объекту, который уже был использован в move-семантике?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/545894/176217)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

И то и другое можно.

Смотрите документацию на каждый конкретный класс:

[`unique_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr):

> (5) `unique_ptr( unique_ptr&& u ) noexcept;` ... stores the null pointer in `u`.

[`vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector):

> (7) `vector( vector&& other ) noexcept;` ... After the move, `other` is guaranteed to be `empty()`.